# Date Format in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I need the date format like "2013-12-30" so I have written the below code.

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-M-dd"});`

But it is displaying "2013-Dec-30". Can you please help me to get month number?.

And is there any possibility to enter year then it will automatically shifts to respective year because by using above datepicker it will take long time to choose date of birth. can you suggest any logic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

**[Refer This Doc for all the formats](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)**

Comment: Thanks for replay. Is there any possible to both type and also pick the date.

Comment: you can use inline datepicker for that

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
```

Comment: By using above format it is displaying like "2013-30-12". I tried this.

Comment: this will display in your required format.check your code again

Answer (score -1):

```
    var ToDate = new Date();
        ToDate.setDate(ToDate.getDate())
        $("#datepicker").datetimepicker(
        {
            defaultDate: ToDate,
            hour: 06,
            minute: 00
        });
```